# all the outcoming traffic is blocked in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, firewall, network-traffic

[image: kubectl get pod -o wide]

I have a pod A, I run kubectl exec -it pod_a_name /bin/bash

from there I can not ping pod B.

I can not ping 8.8.8.8, apt-get update doesn't work as well. So I suggest that something blocks the outgoing traffic.

I can acceess a pod A and pod B from external services but not vice a versa.

I use a default weave-net as CNI:
curl -L https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/releases/download/latest_release/weave-daemonset-k8s-1.11.yaml | kubectl apply -f -

the network policy is applied to allow all the traffic.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"NetworkPolicy","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"allow-all-traffic-in-namespace","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"egress":[{}],"ingress":[{}],"podSelector":{},"policyTypes":["Ingress","Egress"]}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-12-28T14:45:36Z"
  generation: 1
  name: allow-all-traffic-in-namespace
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "940016"
  uid: ****-af46-****-a619-****
spec:
  egress:
  - {}
  ingress:
  - {}
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

I am running out of idea what else I can do. I have to reach my database running on another server from my k8s pod but I can not even send a simple ping request....

I tried to allow all the ingress, egress traffic.

Comment: just did a quick test on a local minikube cluster. network policy is fine. pinging 8.8.8.8 with your network policy applied from default namespace works without a problem. it might be that the nodes themselves cannot reach the internet/your database network. check for global firewall rules or if your nodes are in the correct networks